# T-SQL: Convert Numeric (19,0) to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

One of the Tables in our DB has [Numeric (19,0)] values like this: 1920723322000000 in a column named ClinicalDate.

I typically use the following in my SQL to convert the value to a Date:

```
Select Cast(DateAdd(d, (Cast(1920723322000000/1000000 As Int) / 3600 / 24), '1960') As Date) As DocDate
```

The above returns '2020-11-11'.

Is it possible to alter the SQL statement to get the Time as well?
If it is possible, it should return something like '2020-11-11 14:15' or some variation thereof.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your number to seconds, and add that as such to the fixed start date:

```
select dateadd(second, 1920723322000000/1000000, '19600101') As DocDate
```

Note that, in SQL Server, `YYYYMMDD` is a safer format than `YYYY` for a literal date; this always works, regardless of your version or of your regional settings.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=67b3bf373719c297b3eefd4f8122002d)**:

```
| DocDate                 |
| :---------------------- |
| 2020-11-11 14:15:22.000 |
```